# cakephp 3.0 query data manipulation?

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I'm trying to learn cakephp 3 and the ORM functions, wicht is great so far. But know I'm comming to a point on wich I'm not certain how I can aproach it in the best way, so I was hoping that somebody can tell what is the best way.

I'm using the query builder to load one or more products. In the data that's loaded I have one field called price. This is the main price of the product, but there can be an optional discount for an user. I know wich user is logged in to the system so I have an variabele witch contains his discount, for example 1.20 (=20%).

After the query has been fired I could do an foreach and recalculate the price before sending is to the view, but because of the query builder function I suspect that I can do it there before I fired the query.

Below an example where an search is done on input name. The field price is now standard, but should be recalculated with the discount.This could be an foreacht example:

```
$price = round((($price/$User->discount)-$shipping),2);
```

SearchController:

```
public function search()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //$this->request->data);


    $options = array();
    $options['query'] = $this->request->data['Search']['query'];

    $products = TableRegistry::get('Products');
    $query = $products->find('search', $options);
    $number = $query->count();
    $products = $query->All();

    $this->set(compact('products'));
    $this->set('number_of_results',$number);

    }
```

The ProductsTable:

```
    public function findSearch(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
      ->where([
        'name LIKE' => '%'.$options['query'].'%',
        "active" => 1
      ])

      ->contain(['ProductsImages'])
      ->select(['id','name','price','delivery_time','ProductsImages.image_url'])
      ;
    return $query;
}
```

Is there an way to implement this recalculation in the query builder? I tried to find some info on the web but there isn't much information yet about the ORM options. I was thinking about maybe ->combine. Hopefully someone wants to put me in the right direction.

Thanks in forward.

Changed the controller function to:

```
public function search()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $options = array();
    $options['query'] = $this->request->data['Search']['query'];
    $discount = 2;

    $products = TableRegistry::get('Products');

    $query = $products
    ->find('search', $options);

    $query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $products) {
        return $products->map(function ($row) {
            $row['price'] = ($row['price'] + 10);
            return $row;
        });
    });
    $number = $query->count();
    $products = $query->All();

    $this->set(compact('products'));
    $this->set('number_of_results',$number);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields

Comment: Could be done in using map/reduce http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce

Comment: Thanks for your reactions. I've tryed the formatresults, ands its working, but in the debugger from cakephp I now see only a count. The echo function like:   <br/>     <?= h($product->name) ?> is working. Is this an bug from the debugger? I use the following script as an test in the controller:<br/> 
  $query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $products) {
   return $products->map(function ($row) {
    $row['price'] = ($row['price'] + 10);
    return $row;
   });
  });